# UNITY - Instantiate in order

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

There is a cannonball in the game and as you press the button, it sends three balls that go in sequence, then the number of balls doubles when passing through the place where it says "2X". The problem is that the doubled balls, the cloned balls, travel in different positions. What I want is; cloned balls follow the balls from which they were cloned.
[image]

```html
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BallManager : MonoBehaviour
{
public Rigidbody mainBall;
public Rigidbody cloneBall;
public float shootSpeed;

void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    if (col.tag == "Push")
    {
        Debug.Log("Oldu işte aq");
        Destroy(gameObject, 0.5f);
    }

    if (col.tag == "2X" && gameObject.tag == "Ball")
    {
        Rigidbody p = Instantiate(cloneBall, new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z), Quaternion.identity);
        //Rigidbody p = Instantiate(projectile, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        p.velocity = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward * shootSpeed);

        //Çarptığı nesneyi yok eder
        Destroy(col.gameObject, 0.2f);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `p.velocity = mainBall.velocity;` ?

Comment: Actually instead of handling this on the ball itself you could also do it on the `2x trigger` and there do `p.velocity = col.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity;`

Comment: Thanks your attention but it still doesn't work, balls moving randomly not in a sequence

Comment: well try to to spawn them right on top of each other ;) They will "explode" apart since they are all colliding with each other ..

Comment: I believe @derHugo meant `try to NOT spawn them right on top of each other`, because if their colliders are touching they will shoot off in seemingly arbitrary directions.  You will need to back the clone up a little bit or make sure the balls do not affect each other using collision layer matrix (if that is the behaviour you want).

Comment: @hijinxbassist oh yeah I pretty much meant NOT of course :'D

Answer (score 0):

So yeah you issue is most probably that you spawn all the balls at the same position in

```
Instantiate(cloneBall, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
```

so they all collide/overlap with each other and are pushed away in arbitrary direction by the physics.

---

So the best would probably be to simply make your balls not collide with each others but with anything else.

For this simply create a dedicated [Layer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html) like e.g. `Ball`, assign it to your ball prefab and then configure the [Physics Settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicsManager.html) → [Layer Collision Matrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html) so that the layer `Ball` does not collide with itself.